# DIFFICULTY IN WITHDRAWAL XMR FROM EXMO WALLET

Tags: exchange, integrated-address

recently I have difficulties to withdraw XMR from EXMO wallet.
EXMO wants that customer indicate an integrated address to which deposit XMR.
Because of my little computer skills I was not able to create this integrated address, so I must switch XMR in BTC and withdraw BTC.
But my need was to withdraw XMR, not exchange XMR into BTC.
I have paid further feeds to do an exchange that was not necessary.
I ask to this forum community:
is there any Exchange that do not request integrated address to withdraw XMR?
Thank for you attention.
Waiting for your reply.
Bye

Comment: I ask all community if anyone can suggest me an Exchange that no requires integrate address to withdraw XMR.

Comment: And I answered in the comment thread on the duplicate question. StackExchange is really not the place to ask about exchanges. Reddit is a more appropriate place.

Comment: I would like to share with you the reply received by EXMO.
Evidently they saw my post and wanted to replicate in order not to lose work:Greetings. 
Dear user, 
To avoid an issue with the "Invalid address" in the future we recommend you to use XMR wallets only with the type of "Integrated address". To get more detailed information about the type of providing XMR address by the platform we suggest you ask a Customer Support Service of the platform which provides you with an address you would like to use. 
Best regards, Exmo.com Support Team.

Comment: The XMR tool I use is MONERO GUI, and I don't know if by request they can generate an integrated address.

Comment: This is not an exchange support channel.